# Get the count of matched records

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables named `question_answers` and `question_attempts`.

`question_answers` having options with column name `answer` of each question
and `question_attempts` having all attempted answers with column name `responsesummary`.
Now I would like to get the count of matched records.

"question_answers"[image]
"question_attempts"[image]

Comment: is there a unique id in both the table.. can show us the table structure??

Comment: You need a inner join query for that. but both the table should have a relation with primary key and foreign key.  which will return the matched data from both the tables

Comment: Yeah each record having unique id in both the tables.

Comment: then do what @MeeneshJain said..

Comment: Your two tables are `question_answers ` and `question_attempts`. So there should be a relation between both tables with one key which will act as a primary key for 1st table and foreign key for the second table. For example. your table 1 has primary key id as q_id - question id. which should also exist as q_id in table 2 but table 2 will have a separate primary key. let say it as qa_id

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to give table structure of both tables and result set you wish to have.

Comment: Yeah. Both the tables have `questionid` column with same ids

Comment: `question_answers` table having "question", "answer" columns.
`question_attempts` table having 'questionid' and 'responsesummary' columns.
"question" and "questionid" columns are same.

Comment: How to get all the records of current logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These SQL is useful to get the count of matching records in two tables.

```
select count(*) from question_answers as  table_1 join question_attempts 
on table_1.uniquecolumn_table1 = table_2.uniquecolumn_table2
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi,
Why i'm trying to ask question stackoverflow, it is giving "You have reached your question limit"
Is this possible to remove my earlier questions and ask new question?
If yes, please guide me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How to get all the records of current logged in user?

Comment: SELECT CURRENT_USER();==> if table has user details column. eg:- select user from table_name where user = (SELECT CURRENT_USER());

Comment: Here is my query
$query=mysql_query("select * from quiz_grades as grade,user_info_data as info,user as user where user.id=grade.userid 
    and user.id=info.userid and grade.quiz=12 and `fieldid`=1 order by data ASC, grade DESC");

Comment: $USER->id is current logged in user.
if i use user.id=$USER->id in where condition, it is displaying single record only

Comment: Put some static value and then see. How many records it will display or not you can check after you can convert that value to parameter.

Comment: giving single record only, if i give static value or current user $USER->id.

Comment: $query=mysql_query("select * from quiz_grades as grade,user_info_data as info,user as user where user.id=grade.userid and user.id=info.userid and user.id=$USER->id and grade.quiz=12 and fieldid=1 order by data ASC, grade DESC");

Comment: If not returns the multiple row. You need to change the SQL as per your requirement.